# How to hide a div in smallest bootstrap 3 media resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstra 3.x latest.

How can I hide a certain div, when the browser window is very small (smartphone) and the bootstrap extra-small (xs) take action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `hidden-xs` responsive utility class: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap xs take action after the screen decreased to 767px and min. You only have to create a media query

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .div-to-hide{
        display:none
    }
}

<div class="div-to-hide">
     ...div content...
</div>
```